# scrollIntoView scrolls before ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

i have the following method:

```
public addDataset() {
    const map = this.generateMap();
    this.datasets.push(new Stammdatensatz(map, 0));
    this.addButton.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

(Just found out about Renderer2. I will change this later)

`this.datasets` is displayed with an `ngFor`.
I want the site to scroll to a specific element when this method is triggered, but i won't work.
I think the problem is that the application scrolls before the additional dataset is shown, because when i comment out the two lines above it scrolls to the element.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to scroll after `ng-for` is evaluated, you could set the code to run one tick later:

```js
setTimeout(() => this.addButton.nativeElement.scrollIntoView());
```